# Argument function on complex numbers

Tags: matrices

I am taught that *arg*z^n = n*arg*z only when n is integer. The relation can be proved by Euler's equation but why n is only integer.
Also I couldn't find it on Google. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: When  $n$ is not an integer $z^{n}$ is multi-valued and its argument is not uniquely determined.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.